# Highcharts Highmaps: TiledWebMap doesn't zoom on click if colorAxis type is 'linear'

Tags: highcharts

I've noticed something seemingly sort of odd in the behaviour of the `TiledWebMap` module in Highcharts:

[image]

If a base map is added, and the colorAxis is set to `linear`, and a click event is used to zoom into a selected polygon, the base map doesn't also zoom. This behaviour **only occurs if the colorAxis is linear**. If the colour axis is set to `logarithmic`, then double clicking a polygon zooms both the base map and the polygons.

I've adapted an example showing this behaviour from Highcharts in a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c1mghqte/9/

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing! I've reported a bug. You can track its progress and find future workarounds at: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20188